# TinyMCE Wordpress wpview 'gallery' after drag & drop

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

sorry for the title, but it is hard to describe my problem/ question in a short sentence or title.

So here is my story:
I am writing a WP plugin, which replaces the original [gallery] shortcode. For having a correct "preview" in visual editor (TinyMCE), I also slightly modified (by replacing it) the wpview plugin. But just small changes, like removing the 'Remove' button from the inline toolbar.

All works pretty well so far. One can switch between HTML and Visual mode. The [gallery] shortcode is replaced with the HTML output in Visual mode.

The only thing/ problem is, that if one selects a gallery view and drags it around, it becomes the (original)

element (with the [gallery] shortcode).

I have really no idea why and where this happens!?
So my first question is, if anyone has an idea?

Searching for a solution/ workaround for this issue, I would also like to know, if there is an event fired, when a drag & drop action ends in WP TinyMCE?

I realized, that for a drag & drop action TinyMCE appends a  element with class attribute "mce-drag-container". Maybe I have to monitor the iframe document for the existence of this  element (to call a function when it is removed)?
Any ideas, tips or hints for this?

The last option I could think of would be to make the wp gallery views non-draggable.
Unfortunately I could not find any information on how to do it. If it is possible in the end?
So if anyone has a clue ...?

Any help is very much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

Greetings
Gunther

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listening for a general content change and checking if it's a dragged image?

All TinyMCE editor events can be found in the docs: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I tried it and it works "somehow" ;-). I tried several different events, before I finally chose 'MouseUp' event. Unfortunately TinyMCE has no "drag" events and I was unable to bind a general event listener, as TinyMCE mimics the drag by adding a new div and getting its absolute position. On mouseup the original node is "moved" to this position.
I am still searching for the Wordpress file, where this is handled in WP? Cannot find it in the wpview plugin.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some further investigation I found the function that caused my "problem".
It is the following (in wpview:

```
// Make sure views are copied as their text.
    editor.on( 'drop objectselected', function( event ) {
        if ( isView( event.targetClone ) ) {
            event.targetClone = editor.getDoc().createTextNode(
                window.decodeURIComponent( editor.dom.getAttrib( event.targetClone, 'data-wpview-text' ) )
            );
        }
    } );
```

In my case this is an "unwanted behaviour", as I wanted the view to stay intact/ as is.

So the solution (in my case) is just to delete/ do not use this event/ function.